# Swagger's allOf shows up as undefined

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

I've take the allOf examples in https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#models-with-composition, and applied them to parameters schema and responses schema.  My allOf parameters and responses, however, show as undefined.  When just using Pet instead of Cat, it works fine.  Please let me know how to use Swagger's allOf

```
swagger: '2.0'

# This is your document metadata
info:
  version: "0.0.0"
  title: <enter your title>

# Describe your paths here
paths:
  /test1:
    # This is a HTTP operation
    post:
      description: bla bla
      parameters:
        - name: Pet
          required: true
          in: body
          description: The Pet.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
      # Expected responses for this operation:
      responses:
        # Response code
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
  /test2:
    # This is a HTTP operation
    post:
      description: bla bla
      parameters:
        - name: Cat
          required: true
          in: body
          description: The cat.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Cat'
      # Expected responses for this operation:
      responses:
        # Response code
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Cat'
definitions:
  Pet:
    type: object
    discriminator: petType
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      petType:
        type: string
    required:
    - name
    - petType
  Cat:
    description: A representation of a cat
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
    - type: object
      properties:
        huntingSkill:
          type: string
          description: The measured skill for hunting
          default: lazy
          enum:
          - clueless
          - lazy
          - adventurous
          - aggressive
      required:
      - huntingSkill
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `type` field is missing in `Cat` Definitions Object and therefore swagger-editor shows `undefined`.

Add `type: object` as follow can fix it:

```
Cat:
    type: object
    description: A representation of a cat
    allOf:
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was driving me crazy.